# How to fine tune the hyper-parameters of ftrl optimizer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I found the initial parameters of FTRL optimizer is:

```
learning_rate_power: -0.5, 
initial_accumulator_value: 0.1, 
l1_regularization_strength: 0.0, 
l2_regularization_strength: 0.0
```

But how could I fine-tune the parameters to make it better?

Answer (score -1):

You should perform hyper parameter tuning - Keep a test dataset on the side, and then split your train dataset to train and cross validation sets.

You can then use the validation dataset for tuning these parameters, or directly perform this on the train dataset. You could do grid search over all parameters, or any other method in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization

You simply pick the parameters with the best performance